# list values into array

Tags: php, arrays, list, csv

I'm fairly new to php, so please excuse my ignorance here... :P

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("../filename.csv", "r");
while (list($siteid, $sitename, $scheduled, $arecords, $crons, $sslintf, $customip, $psccjobs, $odbc, $sitesize, $dbsize, $nfssize, $fasize, $siteclass, $dbexport, $chatver, $socintf, $sitemode, $mailboxes, $mailfiles, $oesmtp) = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, ";")) {
    echo "<p>$siteid, $sitename, $scheduled, $arecords, $crons, $sslintf, $customip, $psccjobs, $odbc, $sitesize, $dbsize, $nfssize, $fasize, $siteclass, $dbexport, $chatver, $socintf, $sitemode, $mailboxes, $mailfiles, $oesmtp</p>";
}
?>
```

I want to add each row of variables into an array...

Any Suggestions would be helpful, even if there is a better approach.

Comment: Does the array need to be an array of associative arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gah.... why not simply

```
while($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    echo "<p>", implode(', ', $row), "</p>";
}
```

If you want to store each row in an array, then

```
$data = array();
while($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    echo "<p>", implode(', ', $row), "</p>";
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: This causes a problem with the array values for some reason...  My csv is delimited by ";" so I changed the implode('; ',$row) but it appears that the ' (single quote) values in my csv are causing issues in my array...

Comment: fgetcsv has optional arguments to specificy delimiter and enclosure characters: http://php.net/fgetcsv